# Conditional reading from excel data in Selenium JAVA

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-strategy

**Data set and demo webUI -** Sample data in `excel sheet` (first row being column header) -

[image]

Demo layout -

[image: page_layout]

**Problem scenario -** The data to be filled up is from an `excel sheet`, if the occupation is Entered (that is typed in), it will search in excel sheet's occupation column and populate the data in the name field, for example - After typing engineer, the names of engineers have been populated in the drop-down.

[image]

After the name is selected (manually), the Address will be automatically put in the address box from the excel sheets data. i.e. conditional checking from excel sheets data.

[image]

Now I can read from `excel sheet` using the `jxl library`, but I do not know how to implement the conditional checks from the excel data.

Any guideline / code snippet for implementing the conditional checks is highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose this is more related to logic of code- which ideally should go to SO and not here.

Comment: yeah, I am actually struggling with putting the logic in place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what your issue is, really, but I'll give it a go.

From your explanation, the engineer names in your Excel are used to create `option` elements in the DOM?

**Issue 1:** this feels like something your application should fetch from its database.

**Issue 2**: you then mention that you manually select a value in the dropdown.

**Thoughts:** a data row (as input for your tests) should only contain input values (such as a user would type or select) and maybe expected values to check against (again, what a human user could do).

An end user will not create dropdown options in the DOM - why do so in your automated scenario?

**Solution:** can the dropdown data be provided from the application's database? The values in the Excel then only indicate what to select and validate, as befits a data-driven automated test (each row is passed into a test; spreading data for one test over 3 rows is asking for trouble).

*If not*, then add a column to your Excel containing "John;Emma;Norman" for each Engineer line. When passing the first row to your test, split this column in a list to create the dropdown, then use column `first_name` to select what you want.